Oracle APEX Link Builder - transfer ID to page item from LOV
I need to transfer ID number between pages by using Link Builder and page items. The issue is that on source page I have columns based on LOV and during transfer link move display name, not ID. It is possible to move ID?
In source page I have columns L1_FK, L1_FK and both use LOV (display, return). Expected is to transfer return ID to L1_FK_CHANGE, L2_FK_CHANGE. In Link Builder in Set items section I set as Name:
Name: P22_L1_CHANGE Value: #L1_FK#
Name: P22_L2_CHANGE Value: #L2_FK#
